# What is the best practice for creating random strings when testing spring junit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, random, junit

What is the best practice for creating random strings when testing spring junit?

When writing a test with junit, I use the code below when creating a random string.

`UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 20)`

The disadvantage of this code is that it cannot exceed the maximum length of a UUID of 32 characters.

I have no doubt that there must be a better way than the code above.

I'm wondering what is the best practice to return a random string.

best regards!

Comment: "A random string" is not really a well-defined thing.  There will always be a bound on the length; there will pretty much always only be a subset of characters used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 8 you can generate a random string of a-z characters using `Random().ints(97, 123)` this works because the character `a` is represented as `97` and `z` is represented as `122`.

Then we can use `.collect(...)` to convert the characters from random into a string.

Altogether the code looks like this:

```
int yourStringLength = 40;
String generatedString = new Random().ints(97, 123)
    .limit(yourStringLength)
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString();
```

And the resulting string would look a bit like this:

```
okphrralxtqywxgfnolloyiqfjlgputyzprpbwsr
```

If you want to also include spaces then simply start the `.ints(...)` at 96 which is the ` character, and replace it with spaces once generated:

```
String generatedString = new Random().ints(97, 123)
    .limit(yourStringLength)
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString();
generatedString = generatedString.replaceAll("`", " ");
```

And the resulting string would look a bit like this:

```
ayowotibx sotvonazpm vjnyobdkzajfckutswu
```

If you want even more spaces to represent real word lengths then you can start the `.ints(...)` even earlier or push out the top end, and replace the characters as required, for example for `ints(96, 123)` also replace `generatedString = generatedString.replaceAll("_", " ");` and the result would be like this:

```
hrqobe rufmcknwobzyh whaimaxgjsjg nyxcx
```